# Regex required group of optional elements

Tags: regex

I need to capture a 2 groups that are required, the thing is that the 2nd group is all **ordered** optional elements

so I thought I would do it like this

```
(a)(b?c?d?)
```

Problem is sometimes it only captures "a" only (it assumes group 2 is already there because its all optional :S)

anyway here is what I want to capture

```
ab
ac
ad
abcd
```

And here is **not** what I want to capture

```
a
b
bc
bcd
d
acbd
```

Comment: Explain why `abcd` should match but `bc` should not match.  Your logic is not clear to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because a is required

Comment: Your regex [already appears to be working](https://regex101.com/r/ImIyXg/2), is there an actual question here?

Comment: its capturing a alone

Comment: No it's not, check the demo.

Comment: Isn't the OP asking how to just stop the regex matching "a" on its own?

Comment: @Jimbo Yes thank you!, I dont know why it was marked duplicate ! :S

Comment: Shouldn't moderators marking questions as duplicate at least read the question !?

Comment: @Wiktor don't you think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803221/regex-with-all-optional-parts-but-at-least-one-required (or something similar) would be a way better dupe? I don't see how the current dupe's answer the question at hand.

Comment: @SebastianProske: Great find, I re-set the dupe reason. Still, the point is to match these patterns with anchors/word boundaries.

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks thats what i was looking for !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew word boundry doesn't do the trick

Comment: @TheTrice Maybe not alone, but you still need them. https://regex101.com/r/qd1iep/1/