# Regex : one or many optional parameters but at least one

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a C# program which have many user fiels having regex validation.

I can not find a way to include one or many optional parameters but **at least one** in my regex.

I made the following regular expression:

```
^([\" \"]*[\\+\\-][\" \"]*)?((?<leftoperand>[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]*)[er]?[a]? *)(([\" \"]*[\\+\\-][\" \"]*)+((?<rightoperand>[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]*)[er]?[a]? *))*[\" \"]*$
```

It allows me to validate a formula. This formula has specific rules, most of which I can validate:

```
1. The formula can starts with a '+' or '-' sign, or white spaces
2. The formula contains only "codes" starting with at least one capital letter, then followed by the rest of the code, and can include other capital letters or numbers
3. They can be as many codes in a formula as one wishes
4. Codes ends up with optionals parameters.
      First : either a lowercase 'e' or 'r', 
      Then : an optional 'a'
      BUT it contains at least one
```

I am struggling with the fourth rule...

Example of correct codes:

- D11e
- D122ea
- B9r
- TOTFRra
- APUL2a

Example of correct formula : - D11e + D121ea - D122ra

Example of **incorrect** codes that I can manage already:

- d122ea (starts with a lowercase character)
- 9r (starts with a number)
- TOTFRer (contains 'e' and 'r')
- APUL2era (contains every optional parameters)

Example of **incorrect** codes that I'd like to detect:

- D11
- D122
- ...

Those last codes don't have any of the "optional letters", but they need at least one. Possibilities are :

- [Code]e
- [Code]ea
- [Code]r
- [Code]ra
- [Code]a

Could you please help me?

If you want to try it, you can go to https://regex101.com/

I have also tried to implement something like this without succes : [Regex with all optional parts but at least one required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803221/regex-with-all-optional-parts-but-at-least-one-required)

I just can't find what I'm missing... Any help would be nice!

Comment: The simplest way would be to list all the possibilities, as they are few. However, it's not the best way to do it if you plan on accepting more optional parameters in the future. I'll post a solution for that soon.

Comment: `e?a|e|r?a|r` does this works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex :
`^(?: *[+-]? *[A-Z][0-9b-df-qs-zA-Z]*([re])?(?(1)a?|a))+$`
The 4th condition is handled by `([re])?(?(1)a?|a)` which means "take an optional `e` or `r`, then if you did, take an optional `a`, but if you did not, take a mandatory `a`"
Like I said in my comment, you could list all possibilities with something like `a|e|r|ea|ra`, but if you add parameters, the number of possibilities will increase exponentially.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/3NPMeB/2)

**Edit :** Codes containing non alphanum char were accepted.
**Edit 2 :** Actually `[er]?a|[er]` should be be better, and would not increase exponentially

Comment: Working perfectly, tanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works too.

`^(?:[ ]*[+-]?[ ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:[er]a?|a))+$`

https://regex101.com/r/IYO0Xv/1

Verbose

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      [ ]* [+-]? [ ]* [A-Z] [A-Z0-9]* 
      (?:
           [er] a?
        |  a
      )
 )+
 $
```

The single incorrect codes you want to detect would be something like this

`^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*$`

https://regex101.com/r/2caZBS/1